# how to create button on top of the kanban and tree view

Tags: odoo

how to create button on top of the kanban and tree view.That button action for print the reports.how to print report without select the records.If I click the button that print the all records which are in tree view.please help me.

Comment: Just add the button inside tree view and kanban views@PrashanthK

Comment: That button shows in all records, not top of the view.